# LinearLayout's next to each other

Tags: android

Im trying to have two LinearLayout's next to each other but the below code wont work , it puts them so that one is on top.

can you please help. or do you have a better idea?

thanks?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#999"> 



</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#977000"> 



</LinearLayout>



</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4):

use this just change `android:orientation="horizontal"` in place of `android:orientation="vertical`

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#999"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:background="#977000"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace `android:orientation="vertical"` with `android:orientation="horizontal"` in your top `LinearLayout`.

Answer (score 2):

Set orientation of outer linear layout as "horizontal".. it works

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your first linearLayout at "horizontal", not "vertical"

Answer (score 1):

This

```
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

has to be

```
android:orientation="horizontal" >
```

In your outer LinearLayout

Answer (score 1):

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#999"> 
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout 
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:layout_weight="1"
android:background="#977000"> 
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```